# Can not run Ansible after installing python 3.10

Tags: python, macos, ansible

Suddenly I cannot run ansible.

Whenever I try any ansible command like `ansible-playbook`, `ansible version`, etc. it shows error

```
`/Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ansible: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`,
```

Even if I let ansible run different python version, like `ansible-playbook --version -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`, it shows the same error.

FYI: `which ansible` returns `/Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ansible`

I guess it is related to my recent installation of python. Since I installed a python3.10 recently, The python2.7 becomes not work. Note I did not remove anything about python2.7 myself. looks like the installation of python3.10 changed python2.7 setting.

For most other application, I now pointed the system to use python3 as workaround, e.g. I set `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`  to make accessing cloud cli works again. But for Ansible, I have not figured out how to make it work.  I am using MacOS terminal.

Does anybody know how to resolve the above issue so that I can run ansible again? Anyway is OK as long as I can run ansible. Either reinstall ansible and let it use python3 instead of using Python2.7 or guide me how to reinstall python2.7 (in a right way, not messy with python3.10, currently I am scared of installing python, I am afraid if I reinstall python2.7, both python3.10 and 2.7 will be out of work then I cannot work).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you recently update macos past version 12.3?

Comment: I am not sure what is past version 12.3. currently I am using version 12.4 macos monterey.

Comment: If you recently updated to 12.4, and were previously on something like 12.2 or 11.x, Apple removed Python 2.7 in Monterey 12.3+. I doubt you installing Python 3.10 removed the Python 2.7 installation (since 2.7 was the older Apple-provided System Python). In any case, you will need to reinstall Ansible with your Python 3.10 installation, but it looks like you also need to change your `PATH` settings to remove references to Python 2.7 because you have that `${HOME}/Library/Python/2.7/bin` directory in there. I can write a more complete answer as a post if you want, but I couldn't test anything.

Comment: yes sure, please, BTW, I tried to uninstall ansible, when I tried 'pip uninstall ansible' it shows the same error (because pip cannot find Python.framework), when I tried 'pip3 uninstall ansible' it shows "Skipping ansible as it is not installed." because ansible is not originally installed by pip3 I guess, so how to uninstall ansible? I forgot how I installed ansible initially, homebrew or pip I forgot. Thank you so much  for responding me.

Comment: if I try 'brew uninstall ansible' it shows "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ansible", so looks like ansible was originally installed by pip I guess.

Comment: Yeah, since you have an `ansible` script in your `/Users/<>/Library/...` directory, it means it was installed with `pip` with the system-provided Python2.7.

Comment: ok, then how to uninstall? note pip does not work because Python.framework is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to do some cleanup on your system because somehow, Python 2.7 was removed from you system. This might have happened due to updating to macos 12.4 Monterey at some point, because [Monterey 12.3 and newer removed the system-provided Python 2.7](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes#Python), replacing it with a Python 3.8.9 installation (`/usr/bin/python3`).

---

However, you still have stuff in your environment that reference all those Python 2.7 things, like your `${HOME}/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ansible` directory.

Here are the things you can do to (hopefully) make `ansible` and your environment work again.

1. **Change your shell's `PATH` environment**.

   You're probably using `zsh` since it's the default shell on macos. Have you ever changed your `.zshrc` or other environment files to add `/Users/<name>/Library/Python/2.7/bin` in your `PATH`? You will need to remove that.

   Additionally, if you strictly want to use the Python 3.10 you manually installed (and not Monterey's system-provided `/usr/bin/python3` which is `python v3.8.9`), you will probably need a `PATH` that looks like this...

   ```
   # somewhere in your ~/.zshrc, probably near the bottom
   export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
2. **Re-install Ansible**

   With whatever `python3` binary you're using, re-install `ansible`

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --user ansible
   ```

   This will end up installing `ansible` into `${HOME}/Library/Python/<VERSION>/bin`
3. **Update `PATH` again to include new `bin` dir**

   Building on part (1) above, you want to include the `bin` directory for Python stuff in your user directory, to be able to refer to anything installed by `pip install --user`.

   ```
   # somewhere in your ~/.zshrc, probably near the bottom
   export PATH="${HOME}/Library/Python/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
   export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
4. **Reload your shell and try to run `ansible`**

   ```
   # if you already have a shell open, run this
   # to reload your zsh configs
   exec zsh

   # hopefully this returns the correct path!
   which ansible

   # and hopefully this runs!
   ansible --help
   ```
5. **Reinstall Anything Else You Need**

   You reference stuff like `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` which sounds like you also have stuff like the `gcloud` module installed. Time to reinstall those with your new Python.

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --user gcloud
   # and whatever else needs reinstalling
   ```

---

Hopefully this all fixes your environment. Now you can clean up the remnants of Python 2.7 stuff from your home directory once everything else is working, as this directory has broken module installs that reference a deleted system Python anyway.

```
cd ~/Library/Python
rm -rf 2.7
```

Comment: I just tried ansible after above steps. it works like a charm. Thank you very much for saving my day!